# CASE statement in SQL throwing a parsing issue

Tags: sql, influxdb, influxdb-python

When I run the below SQL and it says error parsing the query. I tried my best to figure out the error but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT *, $field, 
    CASE
    WHEN SEVERITY_LABEL = 'LOW' THEN  '1'
    WHEN SEVERITY_LABEL = 'MEDIUM' THEN  '2'
    WHEN SEVERITY_LABEL = 'HIGH' THEN '3'
    ELSE 'Not Sev' END AS 'SEVERITY'
FROM table_name
WHERE ("class"=~/^$class$/) AND $Filter
```

Error:

> InfluxDB Error: error parsing query: found WHEN, expected FROM at line 3, char 5

Thank you

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> InfluxDB - please correct you tags.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Pretty clear from the error this is InfluxDB.  I have updated the tags.

Comment: From a quick look at the docs, I could be wrong, but it seems InfluxDB doesn't support case.

Comment: `ELSE 'Not Sev' END AS "SEVERITY"`

Answer (score 0):

You need double quotes for the `"SEVERITY"` *identifier*. (single quotes are for (string) *literals*)

---

```
SELECT *, $field, 
    CASE
    WHEN SEVERITY_LABEL = 'LOW' THEN  '1'
    WHEN SEVERITY_LABEL = 'MEDIUM' THEN  '2'
    WHEN SEVERITY_LABEL = 'HIGH' THEN '3'
    ELSE 'Not Sev' END AS "SEVERITY"
FROM table_name
WHERE ("class"=~/^$class$/) AND $Filter
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but now it says "found CASE, expected ; at line 2, char 1"

Comment: Just to test: remove the `WHERE ...` clause. (it looks like the parser is backtracking when it chokes on a bad token) You could also try to remove the `$field,`